# XYZ is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I've defined and created the following model:

```
class Links(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True),
    longlink = models.CharField(max_length=100),
    shortlink = models.CharField(max_length=15),
    createdate = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.longlink
```

My code:

```
from appointments.models import Links
def shortlinkgen():
    import secrets
    return secrets.token_urlsafe(4) 

def DateToday():
    from datetime import datetime, date, time
    now = datetime.now()
    return now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

link = Links(longlink='https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/FMfcgxvzKQmmrZMGFJVWvsLlFPxQKhJG', shortlink=shortlinkgen(), createdate=DateToday())
link.save()
print(link)
```

I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-66d347994058> in <module>()
    9     return now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    10 
---> 11 link = Links(longlink='https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/FMfcgxvzKQmmrZMGFJVWvsLlFPxQKhJG', shortlink=shortlinkgen(), createdate=DateToday())
    12 link.save()
    13 print(link)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    482                     pass
    483             for kwarg in kwargs:
--> 484                 raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % kwarg)
    485         super().__init__()
    486         post_init.send(sender=cls, instance=self)

TypeError: 'longlink' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `longlink` is  static variable, also class `Links` is missing a constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Links(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True),
    longlink = models.CharField(max_length=100),
    shortlink = models.CharField(max_length=15),
    createdate = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.longlink
```

The issue is with the "," at the end of each line. You are defining the fields as their classes references, and not as an instance of those classes. It should be

```
class Links(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    longlink = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="") #or null=True incase!
    shortlink = models.CharField(max_length=15,default="")
    createdate = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
```

Here is the result:
[image]